# Есть ли ошибки вертикального ритма в данном макете и где?

Tags: design

Объясните, пожалуйста, какие ошибки присутствуют и как их исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом - хорошо. Проблемное место вижу вот здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой интерлиньяж вам нужно будет задать для текста? Полагаю, что-то около 2/3 ритма. Я бы сделал текст чуть просторнее и выставил 0.75 ритма, тогда высота для трех строк будет `0.75 * 3 = 2.25`, хвостик в 0.25 ритма в целом допустим - и это лучше, чем возможные проблемы с недесятичным ритмом 2/3.

Также я бы выделил под заголовки...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...не один ритм, с отступами по одному ритму, а два ритма, с отступами по пол-ритма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом случае, если заголовок пойдет в две строки, ему не будет тесно.

Comment: Вас понял, спасибо. Буду пробовать исправлять.